# Kubernetes: cant install Dashboard

Tags: linux, docker, containers, kubernetes, dashboard

When I am trying to install Dashboard, I am getting error like this

> `[root@ts ~]# kubectl create -f 
>   https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
>
> error validating
>
> "https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml":
>   error validating data: [unexpected type: object, unexpected type:
>   unversioned.LabelSelector, unexpected type: object, unexpected type:
>   object]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off
>   with --validate=false`

How to resolve this?
I have used these commands before installing dashboard

```
kubeadm reset
rm -rf ~/.kube
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
kubeadm init
```

Comment: Try to copy the contents to `dashboard.yaml` then run `kubectl create -f dashboard.yaml`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi...getting this error         `[root@ts ~]# kubectl apply -f dashboard.yaml
error validating "dashboard.yaml": error validating data: [unexpected type: unversioned.LabelSelector, unexpected type: object, unexpected type: object, unexpected type: object]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Answer (score 0):

The page you're using, [https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml](http://%22https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) seems to be a `404`. The github page for the dashbard project says;

> "Since version 1.7 Dashboard uses more secure setup"

And gives a different link - try using this one instead https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml instead.

If that doesn't work for you, save the content of that second link to a `yaml` file and run the same `kubectl create -f dashboard.yaml` command